# paramiko sftp.get

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am trying to use paramiko to download a file via SFTP. I create the SFTP object like this:

```
transport = paramiko.Transport((sftp_server, sftp_port))
transport.connect(username = sftp_login, password = sftp_password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
sftp.get("file_name", '.', None)
```

and, I get the exception:

```
Exception python : Folder not found: \\$IP_ADDRESS\folder_1/folder_2\file_name.
```

I'm running paramiko to connect to a client chrooted SFTP. The file, 'file_name', is located at the root of my client's chroot.

- I don't get why I have this error showing apparently the full path (outside the chroot) of my client's server.
- I don't know why my dummy file is not going to be downloaded :O

I will provide any necessary information.

Answer (score 6):

The following code worked for me in Ubuntu 11.10:

```
sftp.get("file_name", "file_name")
```

I just made a couple of changes that shouldn't affect to your problem:

- `localpath`: Used full path to the local file name instead of just `'.'` (directories aren't allowed)
- `callback`: Removed it since `None` is already the default value and that's not really needed

Since I'm not getting the same error you're getting regarding the `remotepath` parameter, I guess you might be using a different sftp server that has a different behaviour.

My advice would be to:

- Verify with another client, for example the `sftp` command, that the file you're looking for is really where you are trying to get it.
- Use `sftp.chdir` just to make sure that the default directory being used is the one you expect.

I hope this helps.